# In Power BI how do you use a where formula to work out the percentage of two different figures?

Tags: powerbi

I'm working on a report covering different `departments` and trying to get individual percentages based on what `department` it is in.

```
For example:

 sales/total*100 WHERE department = shoes
```

Not got far at all have been playing around with a few `formulas` to try and work it out.

Answer (score 0):

so your DAX formula would look something like:

Percentage =
CALCULATE(
DIVIDE([Sales],[Total]),
FILTER(YOURTABLENAME, TABLENAME[department] = "shoes")
)

No need to *100 as Power BI should recognise something like e.g. 0.68 and turn it to 68% when formatting visual. However, if you had 68.00 then it would format it as 6800%!